# Code First Entity Framework Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an issue. I have created some models to generate Database but having one issue. When it generates database it reference two
`Album_id` to one `Audio_songs`

Album Model seems right to me but I am not sure.
If you see the Sql Query Generate by C# it has `Album_id`  and `Albums_id`

```
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Albums", t => t.Albums_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Albums", t => t.Category_Id) 



 - Album_id  
 - Albums_id



           public class Album
            {
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
                [Required]
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string About { get; set; }
                public string Folder { get; set; }
                public bool Approve { get; set; }
                public string Picture { get; set; }
                public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<AudioSong> AudioSongs { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
                public bool IsHomePage { get; set; }
                public bool Featured { get; set; }
            }

      public class AudioSong
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public string Lyrics { get; set; }
            public string Singer1 { get; set; }
            public string Singer2 { get; set; }
            public string Top10 { get; set; }
            public string Top10no { get; set; }
            public string Picture { get; set; }
            public virtual Album Albums { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
            public virtual Lyric_writer Lyric_writers { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Album_comments> Album_comments { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
            public virtual Album Category { get; set; }
            public bool IsHomePage { get; set; }
            public bool Treading { get; set; }
            public bool IsSlider { get; set; }
        }
```

> SQL Query C# generate

```
 CreateTable(
        "dbo.Albums",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false),
                About = c.String(),
                Folder = c.String(),
                Approve = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Picture = c.String(),
                CreateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                IsHomePage = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Featured = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AudioSongs",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false),
                Url = c.String(),
                Lyrics = c.String(),
                Singer1 = c.String(),
                Singer2 = c.String(),
                Top10 = c.String(),
                Top10no = c.String(),
                Picture = c.String(),
                CreateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                IsHomePage = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Treading = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                IsSlider = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Albums_Id = c.Int(),
                Category_Id = c.Int(),
                Lyric_writers_Id = c.Int(),
                Album_Id = c.Int(),
                Tag_Id = c.Int(),
                PlayList_Id = c.Int(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Albums", t => t.Albums_Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Albums", t => t.Category_Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Lyric_writer", t => t.Lyric_writers_Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Albums", t => t.Album_Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Tags", t => t.Tag_Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.PlayLists", t => t.PlayList_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Albums_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Category_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Lyric_writers_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Album_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Tag_Id)
        .Index(t => t.PlayList_Id);
```

Comment: In your Audio Song model you have added two times Album Model {get; set;}. One with `Albums` and one with `Category`. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, you have a model error: `public virtual Album Category { get; set; }`

Comment: lol ye my bad thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       public class Album
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string About { get; set; }
            public string Folder { get; set; }
            public bool Approve { get; set; }
            public string Picture { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<AudioSong> AudioSongs { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
            public bool IsHomePage { get; set; }
            public bool Featured { get; set; }
        }

  public class AudioSong
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Lyrics { get; set; }
        public string Singer1 { get; set; }
        public string Singer2 { get; set; }
        public string Top10 { get; set; }
        public string Top10no { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Albums { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Lyric_writer Lyric_writers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Album_comments> Album_comments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public bool IsHomePage { get; set; }
        public bool Treading { get; set; }
        public bool IsSlider { get; set; }
    }
```